# How to use mipmap in OpenGL-ES

Tags: opengl, android, opengl-es

I have recently entered in the OpenGL world. I am very pleased with the performance that I got with opengl compared to those obtained with a SurfaceView and its canvas. At the same time because of the limitation of the images to be in power of two I noticed that the quality of the sprite of my game is a little decreased. I read that we can use mipmap in Android but I have not found a real tutotial.

Are they compatible with Android 2.2+ ?

Which program creates mipmaps?

How do you actually use in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-six-an-introduction-to-texture-filtering/) is a good tutorial for using mipmaps (and other filtering techniques).

**To answer your other questions:**

It should work fine in Android 2.2+.

Mipmaps are created from your base texture at runtime.

The [tutorial](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-six-an-introduction-to-texture-filtering/) provides full source code :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I meant create mipmaps manually. Is this possible in Android? :)